# Can't access text copied to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I am trying to write a simple script that lets users copy the current url of a page to the clipboard. My problem is that if any other text is copied to the clipboard i.e. the user highlights some text on the page by using Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V, the initial text (page url) disappears/is replaced by what was copied last.

This is my code

HTML

```
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li class="list-inline">....</li>
 <li class="list-inline">....</li>
 <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" title="Copy link to Clipboard" id="copyURL"><i class="fas fa-link"></i> <span id="copyURLText">Copy URL</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#copyURL').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  //temporarily change text in link span
  $('#copyURLText').text('Copied');

  setTimeout(function(){
   $('#copyURLText').text('Copy URL');
  }, 1500);

  //create text area and input value
  var tempContainer = $('<textarea></textarea>');
  tempContainer.val(window.location.href.replace(/\#/gi, ''));

  //set attributes and position outside the screen
  tempContainer.attr('readonly', true);
  tempContainer.css({
   'position': 'absolute',
   'left': '-9999px',
   'top': '0px'
  })

  //append to body
  $('body').append(tempContainer);

  //select element, copy text then remove
  tempContainer.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  tempContainer.remove();
})
```

CSS

```
textarea{
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is with regards to how browsers treat writing to the clipboard as something that the user is willfully doing.  Two criteria have to be met in order for the `execCommand("copy")` call to succeed:

1. `execCommand("copy")` must be called from a user-triggered event, which you are doing.  The function is being called from within a click event handler, so all good there.
2. The element that is being copied from must be able to be interacted with by the user.  Currently, your CSS is hiding the element, so modern browsers (and likely older ones too) will not allow the content to be written to the clipboard since a user cannot reasonably copy text from a hidden field.

If you remove the `display:none` on the textarea, the text should successfully copy to the clipboard.  The attributes you're applying to the textarea are enough to keep the input *technically* visible from a browser validation perspective, while not blinking in the user's eyes while you're performing the action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. The only other issue I experienced, after amending my code, is that on IE/Edge the browser seemed to jump to the bottom of the page regardless of the `event.preventDefault()`. Adding `top: '0px'` seems to have fixed that.